# Parameterize Test cases in JIRA-xray

Tags: jira, manual-testing

I want to execute one test case for around 200 times for multiple test data. Is there any way to in JIRA to create only one test case and utilize it for 200 times just like QC templates? For e.g
test google login functionality for 200 times with different users.
I am trying to avoid 200 test cases creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this feature hasn't been added yet, *Test Parameterization* is currently "In the works" according to their [roadmap](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Roadmap)